# XSL/XPath/XML Issue

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I need help with XPath. I am trying to get the value of the `<color>` in the last `<records>` element of each person.

My current XPath is `persons/person/favourites/records[last()]/color`

My persons XML code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<persons>
    <person number="1">
    <fullname>
        <firstname>Miley</firstname>
        <lastname>Cyrus</lastname>
    </fullname>
    <favourites number="1">
     <records>
        <color>blue</color>
        <sport>tennis</sport>
    </records>

    <records>
        <color>red</color>
        <sport>soccer</sport>   
    </records>
    </favourites>
    </person>   

    <person number="2">
    <fullname>
        <firstname>Hannah</firstname>
        <lastname>Montanna</lastname>
    </fullname>
    <favourites number="2">
     <records>
        <color>pink</color>
        <sport>swimming</sport>
    </records>

    <records>
        <color>yellow</color>
        <sport>running</sport>
    </records>
    </favourites>
    </person>       
</persons>
```

My extrapersonsinfo XML code is

```
<extrapersonsinfo>
    <favourites number="1">
        <fruit>apple</fruit>
    </favourites>

    <favourites number="2">
        <fruit>peach</fruit>
    </favourites>
</extrapersonsinfo>
```

I want the XPath to show the values of red and yellow, as they are the favourite colors of the last record, of each person. Instead, my current XPath is giving me the favourite color of the last record of only first person.

```
<h2>Person Information</h2>

 <xsl:for-each select="extrapersonsinfo/favourites">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Favourites Number</th>
                <th>Last Favourite Color</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@number"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="document('persons.xml')persons/person/favourites/records[last()]/color"/></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Your Xpath is fine (See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEuG). How are you processing the results of the selection? Are you using `xsl:value-of`? If so, bear in mind that in XSLT 1.0, `xsl:value-of` will only return the value of the first node in a node-set.

Comment: I have edited it and provided more information. I still need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the last color for each person via **xsl:for-each** construct.

> XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/persons">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="person">
                <lastColor>
                    <xsl:value-of select="favourites/records[last()]/color"/>
                </lastColor>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Output

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<root>
    <lastColor>red</lastColor>
    <lastColor>yellow</lastColor>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you. This does work on its own. I am just having trouble understanding how to access the elements of records for each person, as they have attributes. It doesn't work in my complete code, as I have additional data on the records element in a separate XML file. It does not match and instead just repeats the first person's favourite color of their last record.

Comment: While asking question about XSLT, you need to provide 3 things: (1) Input XML file, (2) XSLT, and  (3) Desired output.

Comment: I have edited it now and provided more information. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is that when you select the `person` element in the "persons.xml" file, you are not selecting the specific person you want. Your xpath will get all the `person` records, and if you are using XSLT 1.0, then `xsl:value-of` will only return the value of the first node in the ones it has selected.

What you need to do is add a condition on the `person` record you select...

```
<xsl:for-each select="extrapersonsinfo/favourites">
  <xsl:variable name="number" select="@number" />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Favourites Number</th>
      <th>Last Favourite Color</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@number"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="document('persons.xml')/persons/person[@number=$number]/favourites/records[last()]/color"/></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

(Maybe you want the condition on `favourites` instead, but it should give you the idea)